# Properties of $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor \frac{n}{4}\rfloor+\lfloor \frac{n}{8}\rfloor+\cdots$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If there is a condition like $n$ is an even number or odd number or prime number or $p+1$ ($p$ is a prime number) or square number or Mersenne number(or Mersenne prime) etc..

I want to know is there any some kind of special forms or properties related to this equation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is the largest $k$ such that $2^k\mid n!$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know something about when n is a prime number ?

Comment: Nothing peculiar comes to mind.

Comment: oh okay. Thank you anyway. I will think more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n=\sum_{k\geq0} b_k\,2^k$ with $b_k\in\{0,1\}$ is the binary representation of $n$ then  $$s(n):=\sum_{r\geq1}\left\lfloor{n\over 2^r}\right\rfloor=\ n-\sum_{k\geq0} b_k\ .$$
*Proof.* One has
$$\left\lfloor{n\over 2^r}\right\rfloor=\sum_{k\geq r}b_k2^{k-r}$$
and therefore
$$\eqalign{s(n)&=\sum_{r\geq1}\sum_{k\geq r}b_k2^{k-r}=\sum_{k\geq0}\sum_{r=1}^k b_k2^{k-r}\cr &=\sum_{k\geq0}b_k2^k\sum_{r=1}^k 2^{-r}=\sum_{k\geq0}b_k2^k(1-2^{-k})\cr &=n-\sum_{k\geq0}b_k\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Which implies that if we denote the sum with $s(n)$, then we have $s(2k)=s(2k+1)$.

Comment: Wow!! I really really appreciate for your teaching! Thank you sir.